# grep /regex to do iteration / incrementation

Tags: javascript, regex, grep

I keep running into situations where I need to have incremented variables but I haven't figured out a way to script that so I end up coding it in by hand which is awful when there are a ton of entires. I found a code on [this site](http://www.funduc.com/regexp.htm) that I thought would work but my text editor (TextWragler) did not like it (or I didn't do something right). This was the example:

```
Initial Contents:   Var22 Var20 Var86 Var30
Search String:      Var*[0-9]
Replace String:     Var%1>49>
Results:    Var50 Var51 Var52 Var53
```

The replace string just returned as itself.

I'm going to use it to increment something along the lines of:

```
<span id="x">something</span> <span id="x">else</span> <span id="x">entirely</span>
```

the value x should be replaced as x1, x2, x3 or some other "string" + n.  It would be ideal if it could recognize and renumber mis-numbered variables like that grep code suggests. 
Any idea how I can make this work? Can I not use textWrangler? Thanks

On a side note I'm trying to get better at javascript and I'm really curious as to how I could implement something like this(grep/incrementation of strings) into a javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want, but if you want to apply an (arithmetic or other) operation on say the number part after 'Var', you can do something like that using a delegate function

```
'Var22 Var20 Var86 Var30'
   .replace(/(Var)(\d+)/g,
            function(a,b,c){return b+(Number(c)+10)}
           ); //=> Var32 Var30 Var96 Var40
```

In javascript regular expressions the `%`-sign is `$` and the index of matches starts with 1. If you just want to replace the number in 'Var12` with 9, it looks like this:

```
'Var12'.replace(/(Var)(\d+)/,'$19'); //=> Var9
//     Var (=$1)  ^^^   ^ 1 or more numbers (=$2)
```

[This webpage](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml) gives you more information about *javascript* Regular Expressions

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. How can I use what you just wrote?

Comment: +1 for good use of the callback. Can you explain what you mean by `In javascript regular expressions the %-sign is $`, or suggest a link? That one's new to me.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: I have included a link in my answer.

Comment: Looking at the link, I don't see anything talking about a connection between % and $. Is it something to do with JS vs Grep regex dialects? I'm not sure what you were trying to say with that line.

Comment: There is no connection other then the link and pseudocode the OP presented

Comment: Is there anyway you could throw this up on jsfiddle so I can see it working because I'm still having trouble getting it to work. Thank you

Comment: The result in the last line doesn't increment it just says Var9 Var9 Var9 Var9

Comment: That's why I presented the delegate function first. Please try to think yourself too!

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense but I don't see any incrementing 9,10,11,12. It just looks like you added 10 to every value. I appreciate your help but I guess I wasn't clear enough

Comment: @AdeptOfHermes: that's the part you'll have to code yourself into it (from your question it isn't at all clear what kind of arithmetic you want). My answer just gives options, the first one being a way to implement arithmetich into a `.replace` operation using RegExp. Feel free to play around with the jsfiddle.

Comment: My question was about incrementation (x++). Anyways, thank you for your input but, my question still remains unanswered.